# What is the current status of Timeout::timeout in JRuby? Is it reliable?

Tags: timeout, jruby

jruby-lint reports the use of Timeout::timeout as a potential source of problems:

```
   ./app/models/xyz.rb:273: [timeout, warning] Timeout in JRuby does not work in many cases
```

But googling that warning seems to show that most of the bugs reported are already fixed or apply to very specific cases. Moreover, it looks like JRuby's implementation of Timeout::timeout is more reliable and performant than MRI's implementation. Is it so?

I am using it to handle timeouts in Net::HTTP requests, which is a fairly common use case, so I guess that if it didn't work I would find open bugs reported. Can I disregard jrlint's warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

timeout in jruby 1.5+ should be much better than it was in older versions, as it is now implemented natively in JRuby (see https://github.com/jruby/jruby/commits/master/src/org/jruby/ext/Timeout.java) vs the old ruby implementation that was indeed pretty broken.

Looking at the history, there have been some bug fixes related to net/http since 1.5, so use 1.6+ for best results.

So I'd say, yes, you can disregard that warning.